# Make order comment required on specific delivery form

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to make order comment required, when Flex Delivery is selected by this

```html
<input type="radio" name="shipping_method[0]" data-index="0" id="shipping_method_0_shipmondo31" value="shipmondo:31" class="shipping_method" checked="checked"><label for="shipping_method_0_shipmondo31">Flexlevering Privat: <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><bdi>49,00<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol"> DKK</span></bdi></span></label>
```

I can make it default on all selected shipmentsforms with this code below in functions.php, but i only want it when 'Flex' is selected.

```html
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'custom_wc_checkout_fields' );
// Change order comments be required.
function custom_wc_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
$fields['order']['order_comments']['required'] = true;
return $fields;
}
```

BR, Pete

Comment: Where is your flex radio button? On the checkout or on the product or even somewhere different?

Comment: Yes, on woo 'Checkout'

Comment: Have you already tried checking the value in PHP by accessing it via `$_POST`?

Comment: No, I can not make it work

Comment: Have you logged out the values of `$_POST`? Is your custom field included?

Comment: Nope, can not figure it out